# Rails 3: Why might my respond_to statement throw this exception when called from a POST request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
respond_to :json, :html
.
.
.
return_hash = {}
return_hash[:result] = "valid"
return_hash[:status] = "#{userName} has successfully registered for tournament #{tourneyID}"
respond_with(return_hash) #<--Throwing expection NoMethodError (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class):
```

Here's the stack trace...

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class):
app/controllers/tournaments_controller.rb:48:in `register'

Rendered /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (2.8ms)
Rendered /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (151.8ms)
Rendered /Users/myname/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/actionpack-3.0.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (211.1ms)
```

Thanks so much!

Not sure if it matters, but I should add this is called in response to a POST request

***Update:*** 
I have similar code that works fine, it looks like this...

```
 # Store the tourney data
 tourney_hash[:tournament_count] = 1
 tourney_hash[:tournament_id] = nextTourney.id
 tourney_hash[:remaining_time_in_seconds] = remainingTimeInSeconds   
 respond_with(tourney_hash)
```

The only difference is this code is called from a GET request, while the problematic code above is called from a POST request

***UPDATE:***
When I changed this code so that it's called from a GET request instead of a POST request, it works fine.  Your thoughts?

***UPDATE:***
For the time being, I've replaced the statement "respond_with(return_hash)" with "render :json => return_hash.to_json" and it works fine.  Not ideal, tho.

Comment: for curiosity's sake, does it do the same if you use an instance variable?

Comment: yeah, it does.  when i try and return a temp instance var with a value of 10 stored in it, i get this exception, "NoMethodError (undefined method `model_name' for Fixnum:Class):
  app/controllers/tournaments_controller.rb:50:in `register' "

Comment: how do you define `model_name` and `userName`

Comment: i define userName as 'userName = params[:username]', and model_name is just part of the error description

Comment: I can't reproduce your bug, works fine here (I use Ruby Enterprise Edition and you?)

Comment: thanks for checking apneadiving, then i don't know what the problem is.  i'm using 1.9.2.p180

Comment: I just updated my question to show that the code works fine when called in response to a GET request instead of a POST request (which is what I would like).
@apneadiving, were you testing your code with a GET request?

Comment: Yes I did... Still wondering why it fails with POST...

Comment: @apneadiving, I've updated my answer to show why it fails

Answer (score 9, accepted):

due to http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with

> respond_with(*resources, &block) public

It means that `respond_with` method accepts resource(s) while `return_hash` is a hash, not an ActiveRecord object. So your code is wrong. It won't ever work.

**UPD**

**Why does this work with GET and doesn't work with POST, PUT or DELETE?**

I don't know why do you use so strange construction as `respond_with(some_hash)`. What is `respond_with` method?

> respond_with wraps a resource around a responder for default representation

So it is strange to pass not resource but hash.

Now let's understand how it works:

```
# GET request
respond_with(whatever)
# same as
respond_to do |format|
  format.html{ } # will render your_action_name.html.erb
end
```

BUT!

```
# POST request
respond_with(whatever)
# is same as
respond_to do |format|
  format.html{ redirect_to WHATEVER } # !!!!
end
```

**That's how `respond_with` works**

So you should pass a resource to `respond_with` but not anything else. So your approach was wrong. And that is why you have got an error. Because to `redirect_to return_hash` it tries to get its `model_name` to generate a path.

That's it.

**UPD 2**

To render json you should:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json{ render :json => return_hash.to_json }
end
```

Comment: I have very similar code that returns a hash using respond_with and it works great, please see my updated question above.  thanks!

Comment: I just updated my question to mention that the code works fine when it's executed in response to a GET request instead of a POST request. Your thoughts?

Comment: what is on line number 48? `tournaments_controller.rb:48`

Comment: return_hash[:result] = "valid"

Comment: sorry, the statement on line 48 is 'respond_with(tourney_hash)'

Comment: I still don't understand why do you use `respond_with` with hash?

Comment: thanks, fl00r, i'm very new to webdev and rails, so please be patient with, we all have to start somewhere. I understand why it wouldn't work with html, but i'm not responding with html, only json.  isn't the json equivalent of respond_with equal to 'render :json => WHATEVER.to_json'?  shouldn't that work?  thanks again!

Comment: nevermind, i found the problem. i was incorrect to assume that the json equavalent of respond to for post 'render :json => WHATEVER.to_json'

Comment: ok I ve update a little to show how you can handle json request

Comment: yeah, it's funny, that was my "workaround" for the problem, but it turns out that's actually the correct approach :)  good stuff, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I believe `respond_with` is supposed to be used with an ActiveRecord object (or a collection of ActiveRecord objects), not a hash.

Comment: I have very similar code that returns a hash using respond_with and it works great, please see my updated question above.  thanks!

Comment: I just updated my question to mention that the code works fine when it's executed in response to a GET request instead of a POST request. Your thoughts?